# Is it possible to know in javascript if a node or its children has eventListeners attached to it?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So I have a dynamically generated but sandboxed `iframe`, a playground, that will execute and render user written code i.e. JavaScript. The user is able to write anything in `HTML` and attach `events` to the nodes they write using JS. Think Codepen.

On the parent, I have some interactions that determines and juggles the iframe around including removing it from the DOM completely. In this moment of removal there is a need to first detached events from the content of iframe… or do whatever is recommended to avoid memory leakage.

Any suggestions/tips on this?

Comment: If node is removed what memory leaks would be expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to detach event listeners manually before removing your `iframe`.

When your `iframe` is removed, make sure that you `null` out any references pointing to it. Then, the contained document and all nodes within it (and event listeners attached to these nodes) will be automatically queued for garbage collection.